# Telling about someone's patent on the web

Tags: infringement

I have a plan to start a web site that contains a tutorial about programing and algorithms related to a technology. I want to do it just for fun.

Now I’m worried about what happens if the technology has been patented. Is teaching about a patented technology considered infringing or inducing infringement on the patent? How about showing a sample code for the patented technology?

Maybe I should put my question in order.
What in the list below is considered infringing or inducing infringement?

Regarding a patented technology;
1. Telling about it briefly on the web.
2. Teaching about it to the detail with some drawings on the web.
3. Showing a sample code that works if programed, on the web.
4. Providing a downloadable program that works, for free on the web.

Answer (score 1):

The essence of the patent law is to promote technological development by encouraging inventors to disclose their invention (rather than keep as trade secret) in return for exclusivity for their invention for a certain time. The law requires that patents "teach" the public about the invention and disclose sufficient details of the preferred embodiment so that others can replicate (but not sell) the technology. Therefore, it is permitted to write about patented technologies.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have anything to worry about from a patent perspective.  People write about inventions all the time.  You might get in trouble if you reveal confidential information, but that is not a patent problem.